# Animate between colors manually

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-animation

I'm building a button with slide to unlock functionality. As the user slides button, the background needs to animate from one color to another one. Normally there would be some method that takes in initial value, final value and progress (0f to 1f). Closest I could find to that in Compose is [TargetBasedAnimation](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/animation/value-based#targetbasedanimation), but I cannot figure out how to get it working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it with `lerp(Color.Red, Color.Green, progress)` function.

and changing progress between 0,1f with change in x position/width of button as

Result

[image]

Implementation

```
@Preview
@Composable
private fun ColorLerpSample() {

    var color by remember {
        mutableStateOf(Color.Red)
    }

    Column {

        Button(
            colors = ButtonDefaults.buttonColors(
                backgroundColor = color
            ),
            modifier = Modifier.pointerInput(Unit) {
                val width = size.width

                detectHorizontalDragGestures(
                    onHorizontalDrag = { change, dragAmount ->
                        val x = change.position.x
                        val progress = (x / width).coerceIn(0f, 1f)
                        color = lerp(Color.Red, Color.Green, progress)

                    },
                    onDragCancel = {
                        color = Color.Red
                    },
                    onDragEnd = {
                        color = Color.Red
                    }
                )
            },
            onClick = { /*TODO*/ }
        ) {
            Text(text = "Drag to change color")

        }
    }
}
```